# Erro com o Nuget - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou iniciando com `C#` e preciso de uma força.

Tentei realizar conexão com o banco de dados, utilizando o `entity framework`.

No output do visual studio surgiu a seguinte mensagem:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'NuGet.NuGetConstants'
>   from assembly 'NuGet.VisualStudio'.

Sendo assim, não consegui gerar as classes.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Tente desinstalar o Nuget do EntityFramework, ele vai pedir pra fechar a solution e abrir novamente, depois instale de novo atrave's do package Manager Console com o comando: 
Install-package EntityFramework

Answer (score 0):

Tente atualizar o Entity Framework

```
update-package EntityFramework
```

Caso não funcione, desinstale e instale novamente através do:

```
Install-package EntityFramework
```

(adicione ***-Version xxx*** se você estiver instalando uma versão mais antiga)